# Symantec Ghost Deploy Anywhere - Missing Drivers

Tags: ghost

I need to deploy our standard Ghost image (for a Dell R210) to some non-standard customer servers (HP D360). I've successfully done this in the past, targeting D360s, with deploy anywhere:

```
ghdplyAw32.exe /target=D: /eval /ddb=F:\windrivers
```

The last time went off without a hitch, but now I'm getting a missing driver error:

```
Missing driver detected :
Type = STORAGE DEVICE
PCI ID = PCI\VEN_1590&DEV_0045&SUBSYS_00451590&REV_01
Desc = @system32\drivers\pci.sys,#260;RAID Controller
```

For the life of me I can't figure out how there can be a missing RAID driver, when Ghost is using that very RAID driver to mount the existing array to look for missing drivers. I've triple checked the deploy anywhere db on the boot disk, and the driver is certainly there, with matching PCI_ID.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? This is with Ghost Ver. 11.5.1.2266